# Change Movesense acceleration range in html webapp

Tags: movesense

I am trying to change the accelerometer range for the Movesense Sensor from the standard 8G to 16G.I am working on the file Movesense.html proposed on the Movesense bitbucket.

Basically I am looking for a command equivalent to this one : [Change_accelerometer_range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423026/change-accelerometer-range-to-16g) but in javascript.

I've runned through the documentation but can't find anything like that...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The WebBLE client uses the simplified GATT protocol implemented in gatt_sensordata_app -sample. If you just need to change the range, the easiest is to modify the sample and add the configuration change there.

Alternatively you can change the G-range using Movesense iOS Showcase app, disconnecting and then connecting with the web client. as long as the sensor does not power off it will keep the new setting.

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*